# Batch file to Replace underscore(_)from header of text file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I got a Pipe(|) separated file **new.txt**. I want to create a batch file which replaces underscore characters from **new.txt**  keeping the data intact. I have created a batch which replaces underscore even from data. Please help.

new.txt contains header

```
Transaction_Type|Spend_Source_System|Event_ID|Expense_ID
```

Batch code I have written is

```
    @echo off &setlocal
set "search=_"
set "replace= "
set "textfile=D:\test.txt"
set "newfile=D:\test2.txt"
(for /f %%i in ('findstr  "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
type "%newfile%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in ('findstr  "^" "%textfile%"') do (
```

should fix your problem.

---

Ah - it would appear they you may wish to replace the underscores **only** in the header line.

```dos
set "search=_"
set "replace= "
set "textfile=D:\test.txt"
set "newfile=D:\test2.txt"
SET header=Y
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr  "^" "%textfile%"') do (
  IF DEFINED header (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    ENDLOCAL
    SET "header="
  ) ELSE (ECHO(%%i)
))>"%newfile%"
```